# Get-AzureRMVmImage cmdlet doesn't list all the available vm images

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to get all the available VM images for AzureRM using `Get-AzureRMVMImage` and it doesn't list any images like the command `Get-AzureVMImage`

If I follow the example given on the help for `Get-AzureRMVmImage` then it doesn't list that Ubuntu VM. Below is me trying to get Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter Image.

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureRMVMImage -location "Central us" -publisherName "Microsoft" -offer "Windows Server 2012 R2 DataCenter"
Get-AzureRmVMImage : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureRMVMImage -location "Central us" -publisherName "Microsoft"  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureRmVMImage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.GetAzureVMImageCommand
```

What is the correct cmdlet with parameters to list the available RM vm images?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the image you are looking for doesn't exist. Both the offer and publisher name you have are incorrect.

To find an image you need to go through a set of cmdlets in a specific order.

So firstly you get the correct publisher with

```
Get-AzureRmVMImagePublisher -Location westeurope
```

It can be difficult to know which Microsoft publisher you need to select from that particular list. However, if you plug in the result into

```
Get-AzureRmVMImageOffer -Location westeurope `
                        -PublisherName microsoft
```

This uses the 'microsoft' publisher name and gives this list

> Offer
>
> IBM
>   JDK
>   Oracle_Database_11g_R2
>   Oracle_Database_11g_R2_and_WebLogic_Server_11g
>   Oracle_Database_12c
>   Oracle_Database_12c_and_WebLogic_Server_12c
>   Oracle_WebLogic_Server_11g
>   Oracle_WebLogic_Server_12c

Clearly not what you're looking for! if you look through the publisher list again there is this however

```
Get-AzureRmVMImageOffer -Location westeurope `
                        -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer
```

which gives

> Offer
>
> WindowsServer

you then need to find the sku with

```
Get-AzureRmVMImagesku -Location westeurope `
                      -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer `
                      -Offer windowsserver
```

> Skus
>
> 2008-R2-SP1
>   2012-Datacenter
>   2012-R2-Datacenter
>   2016-Nano-Docker-Test
>   2016-Nano-Server-Technical-Preview
>   2016-Technical-Preview-with-Containers
>   Windows-Server-Technical-Preview

So at the end of that who thing, the command you're looking for is

```
Get-AzureRMVMImage -location "Central us" `
                   -publisherName "MicrosoftWindowsServer" `
                   -sku "2012-R2-Datacenter" `
                   -Offer windowsserver
```

For this particular image there are also versions that you need to take into account, so once you run that you can select a version to use, so to get the latest version you would use

```
Get-AzureRMVMImage -location "Central us" `
                   -publisherName "MicrosoftWindowsServer" `
                   -sku "2012-R2-Datacenter" `
                   -Offer windowsserver `
                   -Version 4.0.20160229
```

Comment: This cmdlet is not appropriately designed. I think this should list all the images and as you provide one parameter it should filter just those images. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Mitul I agree, it does feel clumsy to use, but I imagine it is built with the idea of supporting a very large number of images that it would be unfeasible to download in a single run

Answer (score 4):

That will not list all images like Mitul asked. That will list only one image. How do you know that no other publisher has something on Windows 2012 R2?

This will be more similar to original functionality. You specify location and then pipe outputs to next command. Although, this is way slower than in old Azure PowerShell.

```
Get-AzureRmVMImagePublisher -Location 'East US' | Get-AzureRmVMImageOffer | Get-AzureRmVMImageSku | Get-AzureRMVMImage | Get-AzureRmVMImage
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12406408)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This command will list all the available RM VM images, like it was asked.